# Time complexity of a recursive function which generates all combinations of an array

Tags: time-complexity, recursion

The following function **getCombinations**, is a recursive function that can be used to generate all combinations of an array. How exactly can we find the time complexity of this function? I would appreciate the workings or simply an idea about how to approach this. Thanks in advance

```
function getCombinations(chars) {
  var result = [];
  var f = function(prefix, chars) {
    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
      result.push(prefix + chars[i]);
      f(prefix + chars[i], chars.slice(i + 1));
    }
  }
  f('', chars);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Call $T(p,n)$ the number of operations that $f$ would do for an input in which the length of `prefix` is $p$ and the length of `chars` is $n$. The definition of $f$ gives you are recurrence relation and initial condition for $T$. Solve this recurrence. The the number of steps that `getCombinations` does is $T(0,n)$. A number of questions will need to be answered before: How many operations, in that particular implementation of that language, does it take to do `result.push(prefix + chars[i]);`? How many does it tak to do `chars.slice(i + 1)`? How many for `prefix + chars[i]`?

Comment: @plop I am not referring to a specific language here. This is a pseudocode for the task of combination generation. However, to answer your query, we could assume O(1) for addition, slicing, and push operations. Or if you have a suggestion please share your opinion too

Comment: Pseudocode is language too and the assumptions about addition, slicing and push are required to answer the problem. There is also another thing that I forgot that needs to be specified. What is the output of those operations. `push` and `+` I can guess, from their behavior in other computer languages, but for `chars.slice(i + 1)` I have more than one guess.

Comment: @plop the expected behavior is as follows: 

`list          =>         [1, 2, 3]`

`combinations  =>         [{1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}]`

push would simply append that entry to the list.
+ is used to add integers as well as to concatenate elements in the original list.
`chars.slice(i+1)` is used to extract a slice of elements from the original list.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $T(n)$ the running time of your function on an input of length $n$, assuming that all operations are $O(1)$. Then $T(0) = O(1)$, and for $n > 0$,
$$
T(n) = O(n) + \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} T(m).
$$
Let us replace $O(n)$ with $Cn$. Then
$$
T(n) - T(n-1) = Cn + \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} T(m) - C(n-1) - \sum_{m=0}^{n-2} T(m) = C + T(n-1),
$$
and so $T(n) = 2T(n-1) + C$, implying that $T(n) + C = 2(T(n-1) + C)$. Therefore $T(n) = 2^n(T(0) + C) - C = O(2^n)$.